# Segmentation fault in this C program

Tags: c, string, strcpy, string-literals

This is a program to copy string1 to string2 from K&R book.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void strcpy_m(char *t1, char *t2);

int main()
{
    char *s1 = "this is 1st";
    char *s2 = "this is second";
    strcpy_m(s1, s2);
    printf("%s\t%s\n",s1, s2);
    return 0;
}

void strcpy_m(char *t1, char *t2)
{
while((*t2 = *t1) != '\0'){
    t2++;
    t1++;
   }
}
```

On executing this program I got segmentation fault. What is the reason?

Comment: I feel like this has been asked like 10000000000 times

Comment: I am actually very very very weak in understanding the difference in a pointer, an array and there combined usage in strings.

Comment: K&R will not help you there, it is bad at explaining these things. In particular, the part of the book where they roll out  various `strcpy` versions is pure crap, it is very harmful reading. Stop reading asap, get a better source of learning.

Comment: Can you tell any good source?

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `s1` and `s2` are pointers to [string literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal). Hence, the contents of the memory location pointed by either of these pointers are not modifiable. Any attempt to alter the contents invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In case, you want to have a modifiable *string*, make use of an array, like

```
#define ARRSIZ 128  //just some arbitary number
```

and

```
char s1[ARRSIZ] = "this is 1st";
char s2[ARRSIZ] = "this is second";
```